# SQL query with grouping and MAX

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like the following but also has more columns that are not needed for this instance.

```
ID   DATE          Random
--   --------      ---------
1    4/12/2015     2
2    4/15/2015     2
3    3/12/2015     2
4    9/16/2015     3
5    1/12/2015     3
6    2/12/2015     3
```

ID is the primary key
Random is a foreign key but i am not actually using table it points to.

I am trying to design a query that groups the results by Random and Date and select the MAX Date within the grouping then gives me the associated ID.

IF i do the following query

```
select top 100 ID, Random, MAX(Date) from DateBase group by Random, Date, ID
```

I get duplicate Randoms since ID is the primary key and will always be unique.

The results i need would look something like this

```
ID   DATE          Random
--   --------      ---------
2    4/15/2015     2
4    9/16/2015     3
```

Also another question is there could be times where there are many of the same date. What will MAX do in that case?

Comment: what DB is this? is `date` an actual date field, or a string-type? max on a string is NOT going to do what you think it should, especially since your date strings aren't in most-significant-first ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE s.random = t.random
                   AND s.date > t.date)
```

This will select only those who doesn't have a bigger date for corresponding `random` value.

Can also be done using `IN()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE (t.random,t.date) in (SELECT s.random,max(s.date)
                            FROM YourTable s
                            GROUP BY s.random)
```

Or with a join:

```
SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT s.random,max(s.date) as max_date
            FROM YourTable s
            GROUP BY s.random) tt
 ON(t.date = tt.max_date and s.random = t.random)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will work in all versions of SQL as there are no vendor specifics (you'll need to format the dates using your vendor specific syntax)

You can do this in two stages:

**The first step is to work out the max date for each random:**

```
SELECT  MAX(DateField) AS MaxDateField, Random
FROM    Example
GROUP BY Random
```

**Now you can join back onto your table to get the max ID for each combination:**

```
SELECT  MAX(e.ID) AS ID
       ,e.DateField AS DateField
       ,e.Random
FROM    Example AS e
            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT  MAX(DateField) AS MaxDateField, Random
                        FROM    Example
                        GROUP BY Random
                       ) data
            ON data.MaxDateField = e.DateField
            AND data.Random = e.Random
GROUP BY DateField, Random
```

SQL Fiddle example here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7932d/8)

**To answer your second question:**

If there are multiples of the same date, the `MAX(e.ID)` will simply choose the highest number. If you want the lowest, you can use `MIN(e.ID)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you could do something like the following,

```
select a.* from DateBase a inner join 
     (select Random, 
       MAX(dt) as dt from DateBase group by Random) as x 
on a.dt =x.dt and a.random = x.random
```